# how to access a deeply nested button in JAVAFX/FXML

Tags: java, javafx, nested

as seen in this FXML Hierarchy:

[image]

I have :

- 1 stack pane which contains 6 Accordions
- Accordions have fx:id's
- each accordion has from 1 to sometimes 3 Titled panes
- each Titled pane has 1 TilePane
- TilePanes contain Buttons.

Now , in the controller class i have a reference to the parent stackpane:

```
@FXML
    private StackPane stackpaneOfCategories;
```

and it's children, the Accordions :

```
ObservableList<Node> stackpaneAccordionsList = stackpaneOfCategories.getChildren();
```

now after seeing the hierarchy i want to give every single button a .setOnAction when they are clicked,i tried doing that by giving id's all around , but i soon realized that it's not an optimal solution.

how can i set an OnAction for the buttons nested deep in my StackPane of Accordions ?

**EDIT :**
this is the FXML code :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" stylesheets="@style.css" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Lancer">
  <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Payement" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
      <StackPane fx:id="stackpaneOfCategories" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.rowSpan="6">
         <children>
            <Accordion fx:id="categorieBoisson">
              <panes>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Boissons Chaudes + Eau">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Eau 1L" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Cappuccino" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Latté" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Americano" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Espresso" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Canettes">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Coca Cola 33 CL" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Pepsi 33 CL" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Eau 33CL" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Gazeuses 1L">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Sprite" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Hamoud Boualem" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Miranda" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                </TitledPane>
              </panes>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion fx:id="categorieBurger">
              <panes>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Burger M">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Chicken Burger" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Mexican Burger" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Burger L">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Chicken Burger" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Mexican Burger" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                </TitledPane>
              </panes>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion fx:id="categorieTacos" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0">
               <panes>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Tacos L">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Poulet a l'ail" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Poulet Special" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Foie" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Mexicano" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Tacos XL">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Poulet a l'ail" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Poulet Special" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Foie" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Mexicano" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
               </panes>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion fx:id="categoriePizza" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0">
               <panes>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Pizza M">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Margarita" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Vegetarienne" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Mexican" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Océan" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="275.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Chicken" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="360.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="4 Cheeses" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="445.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="444 Special" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
               </panes>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion fx:id="categorieBaguette" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0">
               <panes>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Baguettes Farcies M">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Poulet" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Viande Hachée" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Thon" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="4 Cheeses" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
               </panes>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion fx:id="categorieSouflee" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0">
               <panes>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Souflés M">
                     <content>
                        <TilePane hgap="5.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Poulet" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Viande Hachée" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Thon" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                              <Button layoutX="190.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="4 Cheeses" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                           </children>
                        </TilePane>
                     </content>
                  </TitledPane>
               </panes>
            </Accordion>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#backto_commandes" text="Annuler" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
      <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="544.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Supprimer" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
      <Button layoutX="98.0" layoutY="544.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Imprimer" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
      <Button layoutX="632.0" layoutY="544.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Envoyer" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="2500.00" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
      <Text layoutX="174.0" layoutY="519.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="NET TOTAL :" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
      <Text layoutX="166.0" layoutY="519.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="DA" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
      <VBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Table : 12" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Couverts : 4" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="N° 59924" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ID: H.AbdAllah N°5482187" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="2 Mars 2020 21:46" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.rowSpan="5">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="58.0" text="Quantité" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="181.0" text="Nom Article" />
            <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="53.0" text="Prix" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="6" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowSpan="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <HBox fx:id="hboxOfCategories" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0">
               <children>
                  <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Boissons" />
                  <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Burger" />
                  <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Tacos" />
                  <Button layoutX="378.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Pizza" />
                  <Button layoutX="194.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Baguette Farcie" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
                  <Button layoutX="286.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Souflee" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Could you post your FXML (as code)?

Comment: the fxml for one accordion or the whole stackpane ?

Comment: The `StackPane` if possible, since it's the root

Comment: the stackpane is also part of a GridPane , maybe i should post the whole fxml + controller class ? it's all part of a bigger UI , i have some logic to swap between the stacked accordions,it's a pretty simple ui menu

Comment: Yes I just noticed the `GridPane` attributes, it would be helpful to have the complete FXML, but the Controller is not that necessary.

Comment: i edited it now, there's the complete FXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first this will look kind of complex, but read it carefully and it will become clear.

Basically, starting from the `StackPane`, it will go deep into the structure "recursively" using the previous result (which is a `Set` of `Nodes`) with `forEach`. Until getting to the buttons and then setting their `OnAction` event handler.

```
stackpaneOfCategories.getChildren()
                .forEach(accordion->((Accordion)accordion).getPanes()
                .forEach(tilePane->((TilePane)((tilePane).getContent())).getChildren()
                .forEach(button->((Button)button)
                                         .setOnAction(a->System.out.println(((Button)button).getText())))));
```

The disadvantage of this method is that it sets the same `OnAction` for all the buttons, if you want different behavior for each button, I guess you have no other choice than setting them using `fx:id`s (but I may be wrong).

Comment: all buttons are going to add some text to a TableView, i may regret doing it this way since i havent linked any of this to a database yet, i guess we'll see

Thank you for the effort you put in reading the code and coming up with the recursive looping idea, it actually works quite well.